# Why can't CMake's OpenSSL with mingw-w64-g++ recognize libdl? ("cannot find -ldl")

Tags: cmake, openssl, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, vcpkg

I am trying to cross-compile on Linux for Windows. I am doing this through CMake and x86_64-mingw-w64-g++.

I have installed dlfcn (also vcpkg) to link libdl, and I realized that mingw-w64 has NO ISSUE whatsoever linking the two WHEN THEY ARE ALONE.

DL only:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(main)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/undulating/Manual_Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static)

add_executable(main main.cpp)


find_package(dlfcn-win32 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC dlfcn-win32::dl)
```

This works FINE, no "missing -ldl"; nothing like that at all. It works perfect.

However, for some reason; mingw-w64 cannot recognize this with DL + OpenSSL. This is not the case with standard g++. There is no "missing -ldl" when I combine DL and OPENSSL with g++ but that is not the case with mingw.

DL + OPENSSL:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(main)
 
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
  
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/undulating/Manual_Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static)
 
add_executable(main main.cpp) 
find_package(dlfcn-win32 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC dlfcn-win32::dl)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC OpenSSL:SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

I get the following error(s)

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:106: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

I can tell that linking dl is no issue, but for some reason OpenSSL cannot find bind it to it and I have no idea why. How do I get OpenSSL to recognize libdl?

I have tried linking libdl.a/so directly by setting OpenSSL's CMake's variable to point directly to libdl via

```
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html

This is very puzzling, if it helps I am using vcpkg and using entirely static libs.

All the vcpkg were installed with the following triplet:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_ENV_PASSTHROUGH PATH)

set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MinGW)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no issue finding the library or anything like that. I was simply linking the libraries incorrectly:

```
find_library(crypt REQUIRED NAMES crypt32)


target_link_libraries(main ${crypt})
```

unrelated package but I realized that it didn't matter if it was OpenSSL or not; you need to set the proper lib folder if you're cross compiling and make sure CMake is referring to the correct one via

```
message(${crypt})
```

this will help verify you are referring to the correct libs and you must link it (if the order is incorrect and you get `undefined reference` errors you may be helped by repeating it in `target_link_libraries`

Also for mingw, it's helpful to have vcpkg's installed directory but absolutely necessary to add files in the /usr/ dir for mingw. Such as this:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib)
```

so that you may mix them with libraries for other architectures.

And also preferably have CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH primarily be /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 as that makes more sense as a primary prefix rather than vcpkg.